# Use secondary key to push to invited repo

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have two github accounts on my computer: one for work and one for my personal account.
(I'm on a mac)
My .ssh config file:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com-personalAccount
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_personal
```

This works fine. I added the ssh key to my github account. I can push to my personal repos just fine, and push to work repos as well.

Now, I've been invited as a collaborator to a third repo, and I've accepted the invitation. I figured I could use my personal ssh key:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com-personalAccount
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_personal

Host github.com-otherUserAccount
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_personal
```

Then, in the repo:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:otherUserAccount/redacted.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

But it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've double and triple checked. The repo address is correct.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `git remote add origin git@github.com` How do you suppose `ssh` to guess which key to use? Hint: `git` doesn't pass to `ssh` repository name, it only passes `user@hostname`.

Comment: With apologies, I don't understand your comment. I'm already adding the remote origin, if you look at the first line of the script immediately below my `.ssh` config file. Are you saying I need to do it somewhere else, too?

Comment: What he means is: `git@github.com:otherUserAccount/redacted.git` should read `github.com-otherUserAccount:otherUserAccount/redacted.git`. Note how much longer the host name is in the stuff before the colon in the URL.

Comment: Ah. Good catch. That was a typo, but @phd pointing it out led me to the solution.

Comment: Actually, @phd that's close enough the right answer that if you post it as a response, I'll accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't pass to SSH repository name, it only passes `user@hostname`. So for SSH to use the correct key Git must pass the correct hostname which it takes from the remote URL. With your `.ssh/config` the remote URLs must be (in terms of Git commands):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com-personalAccount:personalAccount/personalRepo.git
```

and

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com-otherUserAccount:otherUserAccount/otherRepo.git
```